# Deploying WCF webservice to IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-7.5

I'm trying to deploy a wcf web service to IIS 7.5. Is there anything special I need to do in order to make this work. I keep getting 404 error when I try and run the web service. I can't seem to pull up the wsdl file either.

These are the steps I've taken

1. Right-clicked on web service project and published to local folder
2. Copied contents of publish to IIS server
3. Setup a new website that points to folder with webservice files
4. set binding to match web.config binding (port #)

Is there anything I missed or overlooked. Shouldn't I be able to run that web service from IIS and load up the wsdl file directly on the server. When I test in visual studio, it handles the loading of that host program.

Comment: must check firewall setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to load the .svc file path which I was not doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on this a little, since this question got me started but there were a couple of extra steps I had to take:

1. In VS2012 right click on the web service project and select Publish
2. Publish to file system by selecting a directory to publish to
3. Copy the folder contents into a folder on the server
4. In IIS create a new website, its physical path being where you just copied the published contents to.
5. Set its app pool appropriately (probably .NET 4.0)
6. The binding port should be the same as in the web.config as should the name. So if you've been working locally and your web.config reads `"http://localhost:12345/MyService"` then hostname is "localhost" and the port is 12345

You can then browse to the webservice by right clicking on the website in IIS -> Manage Website -> Browse. Click on your service name.